# SSL error - unable to access properties of object with YT Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, youtube, rubygems

I am new to rails and ruby. I am trying develop a rails 4 app with the YT gem to display and youtube videos. I see the following error when I access Title in rails App.

"A request to YouTube API caused an unexpected server error: {} You can retry the same request manually by running: curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=bx5BUbiIXFw&key=AIzaSyCy7EGFIu9gFaWOlRGswoCugEi_20hB3js&part=snippet""

I could manually access the details with the URL given.

I tried from rails console it shows the following error.

```
Video.new url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx5BUbiIXFw"

irb(main):006:0> video.title

Yt::Errors::ServerError: {"request_curl":"curl -X GET -H \"content-length: 0\" -
H \"user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)\" \"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/vid
eos?id=bx5BUbiIXFw\u0026key=AIzaSyCpLai69UE3yYSRZKnFrwKkNJ6OIP2SfSI\u0026part=sn
ippet\"","response_body":"#\u003cOpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1
errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed\u003e"}
```

I have updated the SSL certificates for windows. Using Rails v 4.1.8, ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [i386-mingw32]. FYI I am able to upload files AWS with out any issues not sure if that helps with SSL.

Hoping to come out of this frustration.

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to this problem?  I just ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

This *may* be a TLS vs SSL issue. Ruby may be attempting to connect with SSLv3.  SSLv3 [is insecure](http://disablessl3.com/).

What happens when you run the above curl command with the `--sslv3` option or when you execute the following code with and without the `:TLSv1_2` set?

```
  con = Net::HTTP.new(host, 443)
  con.use_ssl = true
  con.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
  con.get path { |r| ... }
```

I had a quick look at the YT gems docs and I don't see a way to set any SSL options.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/253

I had a similar issue and upgraded to Ruby 2.3.0 using rvm and it worked fine

```
rvm install 2.3.0
```

However, other people have mentioned that they have a workaround by updating their `cert` file.  From dblommesteijn:

```
System wide solution would be this (for Yosemite and Ruby 2.2.1):

Downloading this http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem, and saving it replacing /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem. 
Add export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem to your .bash_profile. 
All net::http will pickup on ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'].

RVM and ruby seems to have an outdated CA cert.
```